# Vector sum of multidimensional arrays in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a an N^3 array of triplets in a numpy array, how do I do a vector sum on all of the triplets in the array?  For some reason I just can't wrap my brain around the summation indices.  Here is what I tried, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
a = np.random.random((5,5,5,3)) - 0.5
s = a.sum((0,1,2))
np.linalg.norm(s)
```

I would expect that as N gets large, if the sum is working correctly I should converge to 0, but I just keep getting bigger.  The sum gives me a vector that is the correct shape (3x1), but obviously I must be doing something wrong.  I know this should be easy, but I'm just not getting it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try a simpler case first, say the linear case `[abs((np.random.random(10**i)-0.5).sum()) for i in [2,4,6,8]]`.  Can you see what's going on?

Comment: So, its not summation, but my test case?  A set of N random numbers over (-0.5,0.5) doesn't sum to 0 as N -> inf?  Why not?  And, if my test is invalid, is my summation correct?

Comment: You are taking the magnitude of the resulting summed vector, magnitudes will always be positive when using real numbers. See the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)). I think you want to use something like `[(np.random.rand(10**N)-0.5).sum()/10**N for N in [1,2,3,4]]` to see the convergence of the relative deviation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is is easier to understand you problem analytically if instead of uniform random numbers we use standard normal numbers, and the qualitative results can be applied to your particular case:

```
>>> a = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(5, 5, 5, 3))
>>> s = a.sum(axis=(0, 1, 2))
```

So now each of the three items of `s` is the sum of 125 numbers, each drawn from a standard normal distribution. It is a well established fact that adding up two normal distributions gives you another normal distribution with mean the sum of the means, and variance the sum of the variances. So each of the three values in `s` will be distributed as a random sample from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation sqrt(125) = 11.18.

The fact that the variance of the distribution grows means that, even though if you run your code many times, you will see an average value of 0 for each of those numbers, on any given run you are more likely to see larger offsets from 0.

Furthermore you then go and compute the norm of those three values. Squaring three standard normal distributions and adding them together gives you a [chi-squared distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution). If you then take the square root, you get a [chi distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution). The former is easier to deal with, and it predicts that the average value of the square of the norm of your three values will be 3 * 125. And it most certainly seems to be:

```
>>> mean_norm_sq = 0
>>> for n in xrange(1000):
...     a = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(5, 5, 5, 3))
...     s = a.sum(axis=(0, 1, 2))
...     mean_norm_sq += np.sum(s**2)
... 
>>> mean_norm_sq / 1000
374.47629802482447
```

Comment: Thanks Jaime.  That explains my confusion about the statistics involved. I really need more statistics, I always get confused by stat-mech too. Unfortunately, I am still not 100% sure I am doing my sum correctly. The actual purpose of my code is not to sum random numbers, that was only a (poorly conceived) unit test.  I am calculating the magnetization in a 3d heisenberg spin system, hence the NxNxN array of triplets. Is my a.sum((0,1,2)) the correct way to get the vector sum of my triplets... it seems from your answer that it probably is.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments note, there is no reason why the *squared* sum should approach zero. By the description, an array of `N` three-dimensional vectors sounds like it should have the shape of `(N,3)` not `(N,N,N,3)`, but I may be misunderstanding it. Either way, it is simple to observe what happens in the two cases:

```
import numpy as np

avg_sum = []
sq_sum  = []

N_val = 2**np.arange(15)
for N in N_val:
    A = np.random.random((N,3)) - 0.5
    avg_sum.append( A.sum(axis=1).mean() )
    sq_sum.append ( (A**2).sum(axis=1).mean() )

import pylab as plt
plt.plot(N_val, avg_sum, label="Average sum")
plt.plot(N_val, sq_sum,  label="Squared sum")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

[image]

The average sum goes to zero as your intuition expects.